# How to speed up copying a file to a socket

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am using `tokio` to copy a file (`tokio::fs::File`) to a socket (`tokio::net::TcpStream`):

```
let mut buf = [0; 1024];
while let Ok(n) = file.read(&mut buf[..]).await {
    if n == 0 {
        break;
    }
    socket.write(&buf[..n]).await?;
}
```

But I noticed that this code runs much faster:

```
tokio::io::copy(&mut file, &mut socket).await?;
```

Even when the buffer size is the same, the `copy_buf` call is still much faster:

```
tokio::io::copy_buf(&mut tokio::io::BufReader::with_capacity(1024, &mut file), &mut socket).await?;
```

Why? How could I optimize the first code block?

Comment: ¿How much is "much faster"? ¿How did you measure it? ¿Where is [mcve]?

Comment: You could look at [the source code](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/tokio/src/io/util/copy.rs).

Comment: Well, for one, a buffer of 1KiB is quite small, it should be at least a page-size, that these days is at least 4KiB. Tokio uses [8Kib](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/src/tokio/io/util/mod.rs.html#87), I think, so you can try with that.

Comment: Your code alternates between reading from the file and writing to the socket. In theory it should be possible to do both simultaneously, i.e. start reading the second buffer from the file without waiting for the first buffer to have been written to the socket.

Comment: There are usually OS-specific ways of speeding this up, e.g. splice() on Linux is a zero-copy way of sending data from one file descriptor to another one, possibly in a non-blocking manner. I don't know what OS-specific optimizations Tokio implements, or what OS you are on. Looking at the source code is probably your best bet.

Comment: Files (and other Read or Write traits) are not buffered in Rust. To enable buffering, you must wrap the stream into a BufRead (or BufWrite respectively). https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html